# How to organise this scenario into tables in a MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

So in regards to creating a booking system, say that you have a bunch of pickup points and drop-off points (you can have a scenario say A is the pickup point, B is the drop off, or B is the pickup and C is the drop off). Then say that on certain days, Monday - Friday, these pickups and dropoffs will take place, but certain times may be unavailable on a certain day, i.e. Thursday might not have 1:30 available as a pickup time but Friday might.

How would you organise this into tables in SQL? I've got a pickup table that has the day and times listed and a drop off table with the same, however it is in such a way like:

Pickup Table

```
ID | day_of_week | pickup_time
1  | Monday      | 07:00
2  | Monday      | 08:00
3  | Monday      | 09:00
4  | Tuesday     | 07:00
```

etc, and likewise for the dropoffs. But where I'm stuck at is where/how I can link the points i.e. A, B, C for example - how should I create the table and how should I link it?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to handle it in one table the field will be like

ID | day_week | is_pickup | is_dropup | pickuptime | droptime

1  | monday   |1          | 0         |07:00       |NULL

2  | monday   |0          | 1         |NULL        | 08 : 00

i think you can create all reports using this table

Comment: What about linking the points tho? Like Happy School, Sad School, etc? I.e. Pickup at Happy School and Dropoff at Sad School? Where are Happy School and Sad School going to be?

Comment: add two more filed like pickup_location,dropup_location

Comment: Is this the best way of doing it? Is this not too messy to have it in one table? Or is this seriously the best way? Just because of the number of permutations there will be. Also, when would the ID change? For each different day?

Comment: Yes, i will use this approach if i need to work like this

Comment: Thanks Dani - let's see if anyone else reinforces that idea :)

Comment: also Dani, in terms of the ID, when should it change? For each new day?

Comment: it will change for each transection. sorry it didn't changed it in dummy data

Comment: ID will be the primary key of the table

Comment: Yep - that makes sense